Moving data between two partitioned tables in Oracle 19c
I am trying to move data between two partitioned tables. Below is the sample script. I am working on Oracle 19c and using 12c feature of creating table for exchange. Please suggest what is missing.
your text
How can i move partitions between two partitioned tables. This is DW env, where SRC should contain data upto 7 days and keep on moving to target table. If there is any better way to move data between two tables, pls suggest that as well. Both source and target tables resides in single schema but two different TS.
--Source table creation
DROP TABLE STG_SRC;
CREATE TABLE STG_SRC
(
    STG_SRC_ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    NM VARCHAR2(4000),
    BATCH_DT_ID NUMBER,
    CONSTRAINT PK_STG_SRC PRIMARY KEY (STG_SRC_ID)
);

ALTER TABLE STG_SRC MODIFY PARTITION BY LIST (BATCH_DT_ID) AUTOMATIC (PARTITION INITIAL_PARTITION VALUES (20240101)) ONLINE UPDATE INDEXES;

INSERT INTO STG_SRC (BATCH_DT_ID, NM) VALUES (20240201,'Robert');
INSERT INTO STG_SRC (BATCH_DT_ID, NM) VALUES (20240202,'Keith');
INSERT INTO STG_SRC (BATCH_DT_ID, NM) VALUES (20240203,'Mike');
INSERT INTO STG_SRC (BATCH_DT_ID, NM) VALUES (20240204,'Sean');
INSERT INTO STG_SRC (BATCH_DT_ID, NM) VALUES (20240205,'Alex');
COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM STG_SRC;
SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'STG_SRC';

--Target table creation
DROP TABLE STG_TGT
CREATE TABLE STG_TGT
(
    STG_TGT_ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    NM VARCHAR2(4000),
    BATCH_DT_ID NUMBER,
    CONSTRAINT PK_STG_TGT PRIMARY KEY (STG_TGT_ID)
);

ALTER TABLE STG_TGT MODIFY PARTITION BY LIST (BATCH_DT_ID) AUTOMATIC (PARTITION INITIAL_PARTITION VALUES (20240101)) ONLINE UPDATE INDEXES;

SELECT * FROM STG_TGT;
SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'STG_TGT';


--Temp table creation
DROP TABLE STG_SRC_TMP;
CREATE TABLE STG_SRC_TMP FOR EXCHANGE WITH TABLE STG_SRC;

--Exchange partition
ALTER TABLE STG_SRC EXCHANGE PARTITION FOR (20240201) WITH TABLE STG_SRC_TMP INCLUDING INDEXES WITHOUT VALIDATION UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;
SELECT * FROM STG_SRC WHERE BATCH_DT_ID = 20240201; -- 0 RECORDS
SELECT * FROM STG_SRC_TMP WHERE BATCH_DT_ID = 20240201; -- 1 RECORDS

ALTER TABLE STG_TGT EXCHANGE PARTITION FOR (20240201) WITH TABLE STG_SRC_TMP INCLUDING INDEXES WITHOUT VALIDATION UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;

ORA-14702: The partition number is invalid or out-of-range   -- Error


This seems to be a bug in Oracle. When you run
ALTER TABLE STG_TGT EXCHANGE PARTITION FOR (20240101) WITH TABLE STG_SRC_TMP INCLUDING INDEXES WITHOUT VALIDATION UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;
INSERT INTO STG_TGT (BATCH_DT_ID, NM) VALUES (20240201,'Robert');

Then the commands work fine. However
SELECT * 
FROM STG_TGT;

returns



STG_TGT_ID
NM
BATCH_DT_ID




1
Robert
20240201


21
Robert
20240201



But
SELECT * 
FROM STG_TGT 
WHERE BATCH_DT_ID = 20240201;

returns only



STG_TGT_ID
NM
BATCH_DT_ID




21
Robert
20240201



and
SELECT * 
FROM STG_TGT 
WHERE BATCH_DT_ID <> 20240201;

returns



STG_TGT_ID
NM
BATCH_DT_ID




1
Robert
20240201



Unless I am completely blind, this is a serious bug in Oracle. You should create a ticket at Oracle support.
Anyway, I would suggest to use TIMESTAMP values and INTERVAL partition rather than numeric value for BATCH_DT. Would be this one:
CREATE TABLE STG_SRC
(
    STG_SRC_ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    NM VARCHAR2(4000),
    BATCH_DT TIMESTAMP(0)
);
ALTER TABLE STG_SRC MODIFY PARTITION BY RANGE (BATCH_DT) INTERVAL (INTERVAL '1' DAY) (PARTITION INITIAL_PARTITION VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP '2024-01-01 00:00:00')) ONLINE UPDATE INDEXES;

INSERT INTO STG_SRC (BATCH_DT, NM) VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2024-02-01 00:00:00','Robert');
INSERT INTO STG_SRC (BATCH_DT, NM) VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2024-02-02 00:00:00','Keith');
INSERT INTO STG_SRC (BATCH_DT, NM) VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2024-02-03 00:00:00','Mike');
INSERT INTO STG_SRC (BATCH_DT, NM) VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2024-02-04 00:00:00','Sean');
INSERT INTO STG_SRC (BATCH_DT, NM) VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2024-02-05 00:00:00','Alex');
COMMIT;



CREATE TABLE STG_TGT
(
    STG_TGT_ID NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    NM VARCHAR2(4000),
    BATCH_DT TIMESTAMP(0)
);
ALTER TABLE STG_TGT MODIFY PARTITION BY RANGE (BATCH_DT) INTERVAL (INTERVAL '1' DAY) (PARTITION INITIAL_PARTITION VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP '2024-01-01 00:00:00')) ONLINE UPDATE INDEXES;

CREATE TABLE STG_SRC_TMP FOR EXCHANGE WITH TABLE STG_SRC;

--Exchange partition
ALTER TABLE STG_SRC EXCHANGE PARTITION FOR (TIMESTAMP '2024-02-01 00:00:00') WITH TABLE STG_SRC_TMP INCLUDING INDEXES WITHOUT VALIDATION UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;
ALTER TABLE STG_TGT EXCHANGE PARTITION FOR (TIMESTAMP '2024-02-01 00:00:00') WITH TABLE STG_SRC_TMP INCLUDING INDEXES WITHOUT VALIDATION UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;

Gives desired result:
SELECT * FROM STG_SRC;




STG_TGT_ID
NM
BATCH_DT_ID




2
Keith
02.02.2024 00:00:00


3
Mike
03.02.2024 00:00:00


4
Sean
04.02.2024 00:00:00


5
Alex
05.02.2024 00:00:00



SELECT * FROM STG_TGT;




STG_TGT_ID
NM
BATCH_DT_ID




1
Robert
01.02.2024 00:00:00




Thanks for your suggestion… But I can’t change the partitioning strategy as these tables have billions of records and already working on production.

This is not a bug, but a well-known problem stemming from the use of without validation. If you tell Oracle your data belongs in partition X and that it shouldn't verify that but just trust you, it's on you if you stick a row in the wrong partition. The end-result is that if Oracle partition prunes a query, it will not see the row that is misplaced. If it doesn't partition prune, it will. That is unfortunately a result of the programmer's decision to relax Oracle consistency checks by using the without validation clause, a clause I highly recommend against.

I wouldn't use partition exchanges for this process. While the exchange is potentially an immediate operation (if without validation and without maintaining indexes), you still have to build the standalone table segment - so loading a segment has not been avoided, simply done ahead of time. At the end of the day, you still have to move rows from A to B and that's going to be a normal segment-loading process.
The reason for the error ORA-14702: The partition number is invalid or out-of-range is that the partition you tried to refer to didn't yet exist as a data segment; until there is a row, with deferred segment creation there isn't actually a partition segment at all, so there's nothing to swap the table with. If you did want this operation to succeed, you can materialize the not-yet-extant partition segment by locking it lock table X partition for (...) in share mode. That act of locking it will create the segment, and now the partition exchange will work.
However, why not simply insert the data into the target table with a normal insert select statement? If you enable parallel dml, it should perform reasonably well:
alter session enable parallel dml;

insert /*+ parallel(stg_tgt,16) append */ into stg_tgt 
select * from stg_src partition for (20240101);

or better,
alter session enable parallel dml;

insert /*+ parallel(stg_tgt,16) append */ into stg_tgt 
select * from stg_src 
 where batch_dt_id = 20240101;

If the partitions are perfectly aligned and you wish to load multiple partitions concurrently (with multiple sessions), you can lock only the partition each job is working on by using extended naming syntax:
alter session enable parallel dml;

insert /*+ parallel(tgt,16) append */ into stg_tgt partition for (20240101) tgt
select * from stg_src partition for (20240101);

But unless you do plan to do concurrent loading, the PX of the parallel DML operation by a single session leverages computing power sufficiently well to not need to resort to multiple concurrent jobs. If you have more power available, you can always raise the parallel DOP (16? 32? 128? ask your DBA what's reasonable/allowed).

I tried the alter table and lock table... both are not working. code--Exchange partition
ALTER TABLE STG_SRC EXCHANGE PARTITION FOR (20240201) WITH TABLE STG_SRC_TMP INCLUDING INDEXES WITHOUT VALIDATION UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;
SELECT * FROM STG_SRC WHERE BATCH_DT_ID = 20240201; -- 0 RECORDS as expected
SELECT * FROM STG_SRC_TMP WHERE BATCH_DT_ID = 20240201; -- 1 RECORDS as expected
alter table STG_TGT lock partition for (20240201) in share mode; -- Error ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
lock table STG_TGT partition for ( 20240201 ) in exclusive mode; -- Error code

@KMA, sorry I had a typo in the lock table command, fixed it. But please try my approach rather than continuing down the 3-stage swapping approach. I think you'll find a regular insert directly into the table to work better for you.

Thank you for your suggestion. But below are few points 1) the lock table script is also not working, not sure why ? 2) Regarding insert, it has 2 operations insert which involves logging and undo TS. I need to handle billions of rows and for that partition switching is better than convential insert. Second after insert, again data needs to be removed as well from the existing table, so it has two dml operations which looks costly. Hence leaning towards partition switching.

@KMA, logging and undo are entirely separable questions from partition switch vs. loading a table directly. With direct path inserts (either by using the append hint or with parallel dml enabled) undo is negligible and logging can by disabled with the nologging hint or table attribute as long as force logging isn't enabled at the tablespace or database level by your DBA. Whether you load a target table directly or load a staging table makes no difference - both present the same options.

@KMA Why would data need to be removed as well? Are you loading new data or merging with existing data and overwriting? If the latter, use two merge statements, one to insert and update what is new or changed, the other to delete what is missing. That is not "costly" unless a high percentage of the rows change every time. If your data is substantially different with each load, then truncate + reload might make sense. If you cannot have the partition empty during this operation, then and then alone would a partition swap approach be a good idea. Always go for the simplest option that works.

@KMA, there is no general "this is a better way" in Oracle. Every technique has a place and has advantages and disadvantages and some work better than others for some tasks but not other tasks. It all depends on what you're doing and what the data looks like. Tailor your approach to the specific needs at hand. Partition exchange is one tool in the toolbox, but it shouldn't be overused.
